# MirrorLink-aware app validator fails after signing APK with Google developer key

Tags: android, certificate, self-signed, mirrorlink

I'm working on MirrorLink-aware Android application and faced issues with Mirrorlink's check of 'application ID' after signing APK with Google developer key.

I have created empty project generated with Mirrorlink plugin for Android studio, which created Gradle task allowing to generate `.crt` file with Mirrorlink-related configuration info. I just copied this script to my own `build.gradle` file in the main app module. But Mirrorlink-aware application validator show error for signed APK (standard app signing for publishing to Google Play), while *find no problems if APK is unsigned*.

How to find out the issue arisen after the app was signed?

What I tried:
1) Align Gradle script with [example app provided by Mirrorlink](https://github.com/CarConnectivityConsortium/MirrorLink_Android_CommonAPI_TestApplication/blob/master/app/build.gradle) - no luck.

2) Inserting `v1SigningEnabled false` and `v2SigningEnabled false` - no luck.

3) Gradle outputs for signed- and unsigned APKs are the same, except of output file name and `> Task :app:validateSigningRelease` task.

**AndroidManifest.xml** Mirrorlink-related snipped:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="com.mirrorlink.android.service.ACCESS_PERMISSION"/>

<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mirrorlink.android.app.LAUNCH"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mirrorlink.android.app.TERMINATE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

App module's **build.gradle**:

```
def generateSelfSignedCertificate(version){
    def buildType = version == "release" ? "assembleRelease": "assembleDebug"
    def rerunAssemble = true
    def projectLocation = projectDir.toString()
    def certGeneratorLocation = "certificategenerator-android-studio.jar"
    def certXmlLocation = projectLocation + "/certificate.xml"
    def certificateDestination = projectLocation + "/src/main/assets/self-signed.ccc.crt"
    def certificateFolder = projectLocation + "/src/main/assets/"
    def certificateIssuer = "CN=SELF-SIGNED"
    def developerId = ""
    def apkLocation = ""
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if ((variant.name).equals(version)) {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                //noinspection GrReassignedInClosureLocalVar
                apkLocation = output.outputFile
            }
        }
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("isLast")) {
        rerunAssemble = !isLast
    }


    if (rerunAssemble) {
        def subdir = new File(certificateFolder)
        if( !subdir.exists() ) {
            subdir.mkdirs()
        }
        exec {
            executable 'java'
            args "-jar", certGeneratorLocation, "generate-certificate", apkLocation,
                    android.defaultConfig.applicationId, android.defaultConfig.versionCode,
                    certXmlLocation, certificateDestination, certificateIssuer, developerId
            println(args)
        }
        if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
            exec {
                executable "cmd"
                workingDir projectLocation
                args  "/c", "..\\gradlew.bat", buildType, "-PisLast=true"
            }
        } else {
            exec {
                executable "bash"
                workingDir projectLocation
                args "../gradlew", buildType, "-PisLast=true"
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
.....

    signingConfigs {
        storeFile = 'sign.keyStorePath')
            keyAlias = 'sign.keyAlias'
            storePassword = 'sign.storePassword'
            keyPassword = 'sign.keyPassword'
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        if (this.hasProperty("assembleRelease")){
            assembleRelease.finalizedBy generateSelfSignedCertificateForRelase
        }
    }

    task generateSelfSignedCertificateForRelase {
        doLast {
            generateSelfSignedCertificate("release")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

....
}
```

Running "assesbleRelease" runs with no problems - it produces .crt file with Mirrorlink application ID. But if I put this file in "Mirrorlink-aware application validator" - it shows error report, as follows:

```
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.app.LAUNCH intent - OK
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.app.TERMINATE intent - OK
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.service.ACCESS_PERMISSION permission - OK
Checking DEVELOPER entity - INCONCLUSIVE. DEVELOPER entity not found
Checking if developer certificate exists for serverID="" - INCONCLUSIVE. DEVELOPER entity not found
Checking application id - FAIL. Calculated application ID doesn't mach id provided in self signed certificate
Checking self signed certificate - OK


The APK is not configured correctly.
```

BUT if I remove the string `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` the validator finds no problems:

```
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.app.LAUNCH intent - OK
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.app.TERMINATE intent - OK
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.service.ACCESS_PERMISSION permission - OK
Checking DEVELOPER entity - INCONCLUSIVE. DEVELOPER entity not found
Checking if developer certificate exists for serverID="" - INCONCLUSIVE. DEVELOPER entity not found
Checking application id - OK
Checking self signed certificate - OK


The APK is correctly configured as a MirrorLink Aware application.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guys, I found the issue :)
I have Crashlytics in the project, and it creates file `crashlytics-build.properties` that is slightly changed on every build.

[image]

And yeah, this file is counted by Mirrorlink's tool `certificategenerator-android-studio.jar` that generates appID with certificate. I have done some reverse-engineering and checked what is happening inside of this tool: it only skips `assets/self-signed.ccc.crt` file and `META-INF/` content.

So, I had slightly different APKs on EVERY assemble... Disabling Crashlytics plugin solves the issue. 
You can either disable Crashlytics plugin (bad idea), or use `ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false` param to skip creating unique build ID. [Read more here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html).